# Passing parameter from a popup Scene with its own controllers to a main controller JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, controller

User clicks on a button that opens a popup second scene that allows the user to select some values, then close and pass the selection to the first scene.

First Controller

```
Set<String> set;
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
set = new TreeSet<String>():
}
@FXML
public Set<String> addValue (MouseEvent e) throws IOException {
Stage stage = new Stage ();
root = FXMLoader.load(getClass).getResources(2ndFXML.fxml);
stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
stage.iniOwner(clickedButton.getScene().getWindow();
stage.showAndWait():
return set;
}
```

2nd Controller

```
@FXML
public void addSelection (MouseEvent e) throws IOException {
if (event.getSource() == button){
   stage = (Stage) button.getScene().getWindow();
   set.addAll(listSelection)
   stage.close
}
```

But the value never makes it back to the first controller.

Comment: Because you're not adding anything to the `Set`! Correct me if I'm wrong. And where does the user select the values from? Is it a `ListView`?

Comment: There's absolutely no point in having a return value in an event handler. Since you don't actually call the method (it is called for you by the JavaFX event handling framework), you would never be able to process the value that you are returning. What is `set` anyway: where is it defined and where are you populating it? What do you actually want to do with it in the first controller?

Comment: updated the question. I am adding what is selected from a list view to the set and trying to pass it over to the first controller

Comment: Where are you passing it to the first controller?

Comment: But where are you passing the set in the second controller back to the first controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `showAndWait()`, all you need to do is define an accessor method for the data in the second controller:

```
public class SecondController {

    private final Set<String> selectedData = new TreeSet<>();

    public Set<String> getSelectedData() {
        return selectedData ;
    }

    @FXML
    private void addSelection (MouseEvent e) {
        // it almost never makes sense to define an event handler on a button, btw
        // and it rarely makes sense to test the source of the event
        if (event.getSource() == button){
           stage = (Stage) button.getScene().getWindow();
           selectedData.addAll(listSelection)
           stage.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Then retrieve it in the first controller when the window has been closed:

```
@FXML
public void addValue(MouseEvent e) throws IOException {

    Stage stage = new Stage ();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(2ndFXML.fxml));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    // I guess you forgot this line????
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.iniOwner(clickedButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.showAndWait();

    SecondController secondController = loader.getController();
    Set<String> selectedData = secondController.getSelectedData();
    // do whatever you need to do with the data...

}
```

Comment: the way i do it Parent root = FXMMLoader.load(getClass().....) but doing it your way i am getting an error can't resolve load?  in the new FXMLoader.load(....)

Comment: Thanks James, I didn't know that I can get the controller after closing the  stage.

Comment: @Moe You can get the controller any time after loading the FXML.

Comment: Thanks so much, i got a - 2 :) but it's worth it! learned something new.